# How to make link open inside a div?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, html, hyperlink

I am trying to get 3 links to open in a certain div. I understand ajax can help me do this, but for whatever reason I cannot get it to work right. (I'm new to ajax, and javascript in general) If anyone can help me out, I would appreciate it! 
And I have looked around for my problem, and I can't seem to find any useful information. At least not to the extent I need it.

```
<div id="tickcontain">
    <div id="ticker"><ul class="bxslider">
        <li><img src="../images/01.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../images/02.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../images/03.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="../images/04.jpg" /></li>
    </ul></div>
<div id="calender"><center><?php include ("sources/status.php");?></center></div>

<div id="hallofame"> //**Want the information to load here**// </div>
```

```
<div id="events">
    <div id="tab1">Register</div> //**Want these 3 to be my links**//
    <div id="tab2">Events</div>   //**Want these 3 to be my links**//
    <div id="tab3">Updates</div>  //**Want these 3 to be my links**//
</div>
<div id="adspace"></div>
```

I have this inserted into my header (top of page):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and I have this on the page where I want the links/div to happen. (only tried testing out the first link.)

```
<script type=text/javascript"> 
    $("#tab1").click(function(){
        $("#hallofame").load('pages/register.php');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you made all of your question text bold?

Comment: "cannot get it to work" is not problem description. Please describe your problem.

Comment: Just making it easier to see and my problem is that it isn't sending the code to make the div buttons clickable, nor is it sending the message to the directed div to open the file within it.

Comment: `<a href="pages/register.php" target="hallofame">Register</a>` and `<iframe id="hallofame" name="hallofame"></iframe>`?

Answer (score 1):

There are no links in your source code. Let's add them and change their default behavior:

```
<a data-target="#halloffame" href="pages/register.php">Register</a>
<a data-target="#halloffame" href="pages/events.php">Events</a>
<a data-target="#halloffame" href="pages/updates.php">Updates</a>

<div id="halloffame"></div>

<script>
  $('[data-target]').click( function (e) {
    var target = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
    target.load($(this).attr('href'));

    e.preventDefault(); // prevent anchor from changing window.location
  });
</script>
```

Comment: how would you then open one of the links in "pages/register.php" in the parent div? I'm stuck at this bit at the moment :(